# what is causing recv failed (ActiveMQ 5.6.0 on Windows 7)

Tags: windows, activemq-classic

I'm having a problem with ActiveMQ 5.6.0 on Windows 7.

```
WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55793 failed: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55791 failed: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:55792 failed: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: recv failed
```

Anyone know what might cause this? Here's a screenshot:

[image: ActiveMQ log]

Comment: did you fix this? I just upgraded to 5.15.6 and am getting this often.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run your app/JRE with the following command line arguments?

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

See [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7077696) for more info.

Comment: folks, I having exactly the same issue with ActiveMQ v5.14.4, I tried it that setting but didn't work, @adam-monsen, can you share how did you fix it?